# Laravel exporting to csv is timing out

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm exporting many records(More than 50K) from the database to .csv file using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel and it is timing out with "Maximum execution time > 0 seconds"

Comment: you can try with ellumilel/excelwriter but you would probaby run out of memory with 50k rows. try splitting it into files.

Comment: box/spout saved me here for large files. https://github.com/box/spout

Answer (score 0):

Increase max_execution_time in your php.ini file and you are good to go?